# CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDClo.png)I am working on a map application using ionic/cordova map plugin and i want to change marker so i am changing the plugin in ios platform. I am passing custom properties in marker icon and drawing a rectangle to show the heading on marker.
calling circularScaleAndCropImage method from setIcon method when load the image from local.

i am getting this context error and i dont know how to solve this.

```
    `-(void)setIcon_:(GMSMarker *)marker iconProperty:(NSDictionary *)iconProperty
   pluginResult:(CDVPluginResult *)pluginResult
     callbackId:(NSString*)callbackId {

    if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
        NSLog(@"---- setIcon_");
    }
    NSString *iconPath = nil;
    CGFloat width = 0;
    CGFloat height = 0;
    CGFloat anchorX = 0;
    CGFloat anchorY = 0;

    NSString *iconType = nil;
    NSString *borderColor = nil;
    NSString *ImageMarkerString = @"ImageMarker";
    NSString *markerLabel = nil;
    NSString *markerHeading = nil;
    // `url` property
    iconPath = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"url"];
    iconType = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"iconType"];
    //    NSLog(@"iconType = %@", iconType);
    borderColor = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"borderColor"];
    if(!borderColor){
        borderColor = @"#006600";
    }

    markerLabel =[iconProperty valueForKey:@"markerLabel"];
    if(!markerLabel){
        markerLabel= @"no_Label";
    }
    markerHeading =[iconProperty valueForKey:@"markerHeading"];
    if(!markerHeading){
        markerHeading = @"no_Heading";
    }

    // `size` property
    if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"size"]) {
        NSDictionary *size = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"size"];
        width = [[size objectForKey:@"width"] floatValue];
        height = [[size objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue];
    }

    // `animation` property
    NSString *animationValue = nil;
    if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"animation"]) {
        animationValue = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"animation"];
    }
    __block NSString *animation = animationValue;

    if (iconPath) {

        NSRange range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"http"];
        if (range.location != 0) {
            /**
             * Load icon from file or Base64 encoded strings
             */
            Boolean isTextMode = true;

            UIImage *image;
            if ([iconPath rangeOfString:@"data:image/"].location != NSNotFound &&
                [iconPath rangeOfString:@";base64,"].location != NSNotFound) {

                /**
                 * Base64 icon
                 */
                isTextMode = false;
                NSArray *tmp = [iconPath componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

                NSData *decodedData;
#if !defined(__IPHONE_8_0)
                if ([PluginUtil isIOS7_OR_OVER]) {
                    decodedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:tmp[1]];
                } else {
#if !defined(__IPHONE_7_0)
                    decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:(NSString *)tmp[1]];
#endif
                }
#else
                decodedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:tmp[1]];
#endif
                image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:decodedData];
                if (width && height) {
                    image = [image resize:width height:height];
                }
                if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
                    NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 1");
                    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                    image = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];
                }

                // The `anchor` property for the icon
                if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"]) {
                    NSArray *points = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"];
                    anchorX = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / image.size.width;
                    anchorY = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / image.size.height;
                    marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY);
                }

            } else {
                /**
                 * Load the icon from local path
                 */

                range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"cdvfile://"];
                if (range.location != NSNotFound) {

                    iconPath = [PluginUtil getAbsolutePathFromCDVFilePath:self.webView cdvFilePath:iconPath];

                    if (iconPath == nil) {
                        if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
                            NSLog(@"(debug)Can not convert '%@' to device full path.", iconPath);
                        }
                        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
                        return;
                    }
                }


                range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"://"];
                if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
                    range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"www/"];
                    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
                        iconPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www/%@", iconPath];
                    }

                    range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"/"];
                    if (range.location != 0) {
                      // Get the absolute path of the www folder.
                      // https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/1e2593f42455aa78d7fff7400a834beb37a0683c/src/ios/CDVFile.m#L506
                      NSString *applicationDirectory = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] absoluteString];
                      iconPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", applicationDirectory, iconPath];
                    } else {
                      iconPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", iconPath];
                    }
                }

                range = [iconPath rangeOfString:@"file://"];
                if (range.location != NSNotFound) {

                    #ifdef __CORDOVA_4_0_0
                        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:iconPath];
                        NSURL *resolvedFileURL = [fileURL URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
                        iconPath = [resolvedFileURL path];
                    #else
                        iconPath = [iconPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];
                    #endif

                    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:iconPath]) {
                        if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
                            NSLog(@"(debug)There is no file at '%@'.", iconPath);
                        }
                        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
                        return;
                    }
                }

                image = [UIImage imageNamed:iconPath];

                if (width && height) {
                    image = [image resize:width height:height];
                }
            }
            if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
                NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 2");
                CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];});

            }

            marker.icon = image;
            // The `anchor` property for the icon
            if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"]) {
                NSArray *points = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"];
                anchorX = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / image.size.width;
                anchorY = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / image.size.height;
                marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY);
            }

            // The `infoWindowAnchor` property
            if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"infoWindowAnchor"]) {
                NSArray *points = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"infoWindowAnchor"];
                anchorX = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / image.size.width;
                anchorY = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / image.size.height;
                marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY);
            }


            // The `visible` property
            if (iconProperty[@"visible"]) {
                marker.map = self.mapCtrl.map;
            }

            if (animation) {
                // Do animation, then send the result
                [self setMarkerAnimation_:animation marker:marker pluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
            } else {
                // Send the result
                [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
            }
        } else {
            if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
                NSLog(@"---- Load the icon from the internet");
            }
            /***
             * Load the icon from the internet
             */

            /*
             // download the image asynchronously
             R9HTTPRequest *request = [[R9HTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
             [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
             [request setTimeoutInterval:5];
             [request setFailedHandler:^(NSError *error){}];
             */


            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:iconPath];

                [self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {

                    if (!succeeded) {

                        // The `visible` property
                        if ([[iconProperty valueForKey:@"visible"] boolValue]) {
                            marker.map = self.mapCtrl.map;
                        }

                        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
                        return;
                    }

                    if (width && height) {
                        image = [image resize:width height:height];
                    }

                    if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
                        NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 3");
                        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                        image = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        marker.icon = image;

                        // The `anchor` property for the icon
                        if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"]) {
                            NSArray *points = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"anchor"];
                            CGFloat anchorX = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / image.size.width;
                            CGFloat anchorY = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / image.size.height;
                            marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY);
                        }


                        // The `infoWindowAnchor` property
                        if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"infoWindowAnchor"]) {
                            NSArray *points = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"infoWindowAnchor"];
                            CGFloat anchorX = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / image.size.width;
                            CGFloat anchorY = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / image.size.height;
                            marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY);
                        }

                        // The `visible` property
                        if ([[iconProperty valueForKey:@"visible"] boolValue]) {
                            marker.map = self.mapCtrl.map;
                        }


                        if (animation) {
                            // Do animation, then send the result
                            if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
                                NSLog(@"---- do animation animation = %@", animation);
                            }
                            [self setMarkerAnimation_:animation marker:marker pluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
                        } else {
                            // Send the result
                            if (self.mapCtrl.debuggable) {
                                NSLog(@"---- no marker animation");
                            }
                            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
                        }

                    });


                }];

            });


        }
    } else if ([iconProperty valueForKey:@"iconColor"]) {
        UIColor *iconColor = [iconProperty valueForKey:@"iconColor"];
        marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:iconColor];

        // The `visible` property
        if ([[iconProperty valueForKey:@"visible"] boolValue]) {
            marker.map = self.mapCtrl.map;
        }

        if (animation) {
            // Do animation, then send the result
            [self setMarkerAnimation_:animation marker:marker pluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
        } else {
            // Send the result
            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
        }

    }

}
`
- (UIImage*)circularScaleAndCropImage:(UIImage*)image frame:(CGRect)frame color:(NSString *)color label :(NSString *)label heading :(NSString *)heading{
    // This function returns a newImage, based on image, that has been:
    // - scaled to fit in (CGRect) rect
    // - and cropped within a circle of radius: rectWidth/2

    NSLog(@"function called");
    NSString *htmlTemplate =
    @"<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "body span{\n"
    "font-family: HelveticaNeue;\n"
    "border-radius : 3px;\n"
    "font-size: 11px;\n"
    "font-weight: normal;\n"
    "text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "</style>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "%@\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>";
    //Create the bitmap graphics context
    NSString *noLabel = @"no_Label";
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.width), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSLog(@"function called");
    //Get the width and heights
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat rectWidth = frame.size.width;

    //Calculate the centre of the circle
    CGFloat imageCentreX = imageWidth/2;

    //Calculate the radius of circle
    CGFloat radius = rectWidth/2;

    //Create circle
    CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddArc (context, imageCentreX, imageCentreX, radius-3, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
    CGContextClosePath (context);

    //Crop circle
    CGContextClip (context);

    //Create rectangle for image and draw in it.
    CGRect NewMmyRect = CGRectMake(0,0,  imageWidth, imageHeight);
    [[self colorFromHexString: color] setFill];  // changes are here
    UIRectFill(NewMmyRect);               // and here

    if(label != noLabel){
        NSString * htmlString = label;
        NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlTemplate, htmlString]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

        UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:NewMmyRect];
        myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [myLabel sizeToFit];
        [myLabel drawTextInRect:NewMmyRect];
    } else{
        [image drawInRect:NewMmyRect];
    }

    //Convert context into an image and remoove the context
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Create a new Image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*2, (imageWidth-2)*1.5-8+25), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Create a rectange around the circled image and draw stroke on it.
    float frameWidth =frame.size.width*2;
    float newRectWidth =rectWidth-5;
    CGRect NewMmyRect2 = CGRectMake((frameWidth/2-newRectWidth/2),25,  rectWidth-5, rectWidth-5);
    [newImage drawInRect:NewMmyRect2];


    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NewMmyRect2 cornerRadius:imageWidth];
    bezierPath.lineWidth =4;
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context2,  [self colorFromHexString: color].CGColor);
    [bezierPath stroke];


    //Create a triangle for bottom pin
    CGContextBeginPath(context2);

    float fithpart =frameWidth/6;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context2, fithpart*2.5, newRectWidth+25);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context2,fithpart*3.5, newRectWidth+25);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context2,(frameWidth/2), newRectWidth+25+12);

    CGContextClosePath(context2);



    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context2, [self colorFromHexString:color].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context2);
    NSString *noLabel2 = @"no_Heading";
    if(heading != noLabel2){


        CGRect rect1 = NewMmyRect;
        CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width*2, 22);
        UIBezierPath *bezierCorner = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect2 cornerRadius:3.00];
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context2,  [self colorFromHexString: color].CGColor);
        [bezierCorner fill];
        NSString * htmlStringHeading = heading;
        NSAttributedString * attrStr2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlTemplate, htmlStringHeading] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        //UIRectFill(rect2);
        UILabel * myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect2];
        myLabel2.attributedText = attrStr2;
        myLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
        [myLabel2 sizeToFit];
        [myLabel2 drawTextInRect:rect2];
        CGRectUnion(rect2, rect1);
    }

    UIImage *newImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage2;
}
```

see the picture and please suggest me solution about the problem

Comment: "see the picture and please suggest me solution about the problem" - the picture is missing?

Comment: Most of the time this error happens, because such functions are not performed in the mainthread. Please make sure, it runs on mainThread

Comment: i have edited the post and provided the picture link

Comment: How / When do you call this method? Can you share the code for this?

Comment: i am new to objective c and ios development so can u please elaborate i don't know how to check mainThread

Comment: Perform the call of the function within the following block: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[circularScaleAndCropImage:....];});  Further described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
                    NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 1");
                    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                    image = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];
                }

Comment: calling this methd in (void)setIcon_ method of the plugin in marker.m class

Comment: Can you update the question? Its better readable in there :-) where is the function "setIcon_" called?

Comment: let me try dispatch_async. can i assign this to image because this function returns image at the end ???

Comment: You can return variables from blocks, but in this case, just shift everything related to the image to your async block. Or post your code in the question, then its easier to provide a proper solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

it was a problem with width and height i was passing to the rectangle.
width and height values were 0.

Thats why i was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem lies here, where you want to download your image asynchronously.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:iconPath];
    [self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {

    ...
});
```

The approach is just fine, the basic problem is: the returned image shall not be processed in the main thread, while the processing functionality does actually require being performed in the mainthread.

This is also the reason, why later on in the code block, you want to perform the changes back in the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    marker.icon = image;
    ...
});
```

So what you have to do is: perform the image processing in the main thread - in your case, you could even take the following dispatcher for this:

so instead of:

```
if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
    NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 3");
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    image = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    marker.icon = image;
    ...
});
```

Move the processing into the main thread, so it will eventually look like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if([iconType isEqualToString:ImageMarkerString ]){
        NSLog(@"ICON Marker Type Condition True 3");
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
        image = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:newRect color:borderColor label : markerLabel heading :markerHeading];
    }
    marker.icon = image;

    ...
});
```

Some additional info how to use the dispatchers can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Here are some die notes regarding the context, in which the actions should be performed:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: after the function call i have checked by printing logs that the execution stops at this point of code
 `CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddArc (context, imageCentreX, imageCentreX, radius-3, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
    CGContextClosePath (context);`

Comment: Thanks for helping me 
i got it

Comment: In case my answer helped you out, please mark it as accepted answer. If something else solved your problem, please describe it, so other can learn from this :)

Comment: i have posted the answer and explained whats the problem and how i solved it you can see and mark this as answer thanks :)